# cURL Html output different from original page when rendered

Tags: php, html, curl, file-get-contents

I am working on a project that involves fetching pages with cURL or file_get_contents. The problem is that when i try to echo the html fetched, the output seem to be different from the original page, not all images show up. Please i would like to know if there is a solution. My code

```
    <?php
    //Get the url
    $url = "http://www.google.com";

    //Get the html of url
    function get_data($url) 
    { 
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 5;
       //$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.";
       $userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;

    }

    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: assuming you're not fetching google - but you're not providing enough information to help. Give the actual page fetched and show what you expect vs what you get, perhaps (a small sample, not the entire page)

Comment: are the images that don't show up relative locations? /images/blah.jpg wouldn't show up if rendered locally, but http://foo.com/images/blah.jpg would be able to find the correct image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `<base>` to specify a base url for all relative links:

If you curl `http://example.com/thisPage.html` then add a `base` tag in your echoed output of ''. This should technically be in the `<head>`, but this will work:

```
echo '<base href="http://example.com/" />';
echo $html;
```

[**Live example w `<base>`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oj0WbG) is [**broken w/o `<base>`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bfxj3G)

Comment: Brilliant - much better than rewriting all links manually. Here's an easy way to put the <base> into the right place: `$response = preg_replace("/<head>/i", "<head><base href='$url' />", $response, 1);`

Comment: This solved as issue that took me 3 hours to find! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
    //Get the html of url
    function get_data($url) 
    { 
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 5;
       //$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.";
       $userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;

    }

$parse = parse_url($url);
$count =  "http://".$parse['host'].dirname($parse['path'])."//";

$page = str_replace("<head>", "<head>\n<base href=\"" . $count . "\" />", $page);
$page = str_replace("<HEAD>", "<head>\n<base href=\"" . $count . "\" />", $page);
echo $page;
?>
```