# Relative URLs and cURL - is there a way to make sure assets from a remote page have the right base url?

Tags: php, curl, authentication, base-url

I have a curl script that seems to be doing what I want, but I can't verify because nothing is loading on the page.

If I view the source, I can see the html of the page I'm requesting.

When I check the console, it shows about nine 404 errors for resources that are using my url as the base instead of the url of the site they are actually hosted on...is there a way to prevent this with relative urls in curl requests?

These urls should have the base url of the other site - I compared so I believe it is pulling the page but just can't load because the urls are wrong.

Do I need to somehow do a string replace with php? Is that possible?

```
<?php 
function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login); 
} 
function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}
function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
    $headers = array("Expect:");
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($datapost);
    unset($datapost);    
}
?>
<?php
login("https://example.domain.com/login","email=test.user@mailinator.com&password=12345678987654321");
   echo grab_page("https://example.domain.com/home");
?>
```

Comment: If there's any other information I need to add please let me know - I tried to be thorough - the code, what I can see, errors - I'm not sure what else to look for.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone this might help I had to edit the last few lines of code like this:

```
<?php
    login("https://example.domain.com/login","email=test.user@mailinator.com&password=12345678987654321");
    echo '<base href="https://example.domain.com" />';
    echo grab_page("https://example.domain.com/home");
?>
```

answer found here: [cURL Html output different from original page when rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518598/curl-html-output-different-from-original-page-when-rendered)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Placing right above my echo $htmlContent saved the day!